# How can I fix/get rid of these Eclipse 2019.09 errors?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, slf4j

I'm using an Eclipse CDT distribution from 2019-09 (v4.13, build id: I20190916-1045), on a SLES 15 machine (don't ask...)

When I start Eclipse up, I get the following text on my console:

```
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: /home/lh156516/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.13.0.20190716-1624.xml
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://470.fwk441444733:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://470.fwk441444733:2/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

My questions:

1. Why was The "logback configuration bundle activated before the state location was initialized"?
2. How can I get the "bundle" to be activated only when its supposed to?
3. Why does the Simple Logging Facade for Java's Class path contain multiple SLF4J bindings?
4. Can I, and should I change the class path so that it only contains a single "SLF4J binding"?

Note: I'm not much of a "Java guy" and am not familiar with the inner workings of the Eclipse platform; think of me as a lay Eclipse user.

Comment: This looks like an incompatibility between plugins/bundles you have in your retro Eclipse (m2e is the Maven support that is not included in the C/C++ Eclipse IDE by default). But these are warnings, not errors, about initialization of logging you can ignore. Eclipse is an OSGi application, so there is no flat classpath you can change like in a plain Java application. Bundles are normally activated when they are needed (lazy), but SLF4J was not created with bundles that can be started and stopped at runtime in mind. Whatever, don't waste time with such an old Eclipse that is 5 releases behind.

Comment: @howlger: So, you're suggesting I update to a new release and try there?

Comment: I say that this is just noise that can be ignored (see [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=473789#c1) and [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=520754)). Independent from that, please make sure you are not using software that is no longer maintained ([Eclipse does not have an LTS version](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/lts-iwg/msg00115.html)).

Comment: @howlger: I realize this _can_ be ignored. But I want to make it go away and not litter my console.

Comment: Can you reproduce this with the Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers 2020-12? I can't.

Comment: @howlger: With 2020-12, I get different errors: `SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation`.

Comment: As already mentioned, that's noise that can be ignored, not errors. The Eclipse platform and JDT does not use SLF4J. Find out by which other plugins it is caused (in _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details_ you can uninstall parts until the output disappear) and report it to the Eclipse project providing the plugins causing this.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug, known since 2016:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=506676